# how to forward my message to other public channels in telegram?

Tags: bots, telegram, channel

I have created a public telegram channel. I would like to forward my messages to other related channels. I tried forwarding messages to other channels, but it says "sorry, no way to forward here". I am confused with the bots and the way to use them.

What is the procedure to post in other channels?

Comment: welcome to SO.  Typically people will give enough content to setup their issue in order for us to help.  You have not provided much information here.

Comment: Looks like you are not using bot/program, just want to share your post to other channels which you have no permission.

Comment: CAN YOU RECOMMEND WHICH BOT TO USE TO FORWARD MY MESSAGES TO OTHER CHANNEL TO WHICH I HAVE NO PERMISSION ?